# Windows 10 modern app or UWP app data folder

Tags: windows, uwp

I need to find the app data folder of a Windows 10 UWP app from within a Win32 app or powershell script (not sandboxed and sufficient privilege).  If I know the AUMID, is there a way to find out where the sandboxed app files are installed?

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer:

From the command line: cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\AUMID